# WindowSoftInput: adjustPan and adjustNothing custom behavior

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode, adjustpan

We have toolbar, tablayout, editText and a view that has been set to alignParentBottom. When user clicks on editText (focus), we do not want our bottom view to be brought up, pushed up and hence, we can use adjustNothing in manifest but we also do not want our toolbar and tablayout to be pushed up! If we use adjustPan, it will bring bottom view up and if we use adjustNothing, it will push toolbar and tablayout up (even with collapseMode pin or exitUntillCollapse scroll flags) that we do not want!

Any solution will be appreciated!
Thank you.